# How do I force SQLite to materialize a subquery?

Tags: sqlite

Because SQLite sometimes evaluates functions like `random()` more than once if they appear in a subquery, which may be a [bug](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg57688.html), eg:

```
select op, op from (select abs(random())%10 as op from (select 1));
3|1
```

I need an easy way to force SQLite to materialize the subquery so that `random()` is only evaluated once

*this is a simplified example for demonstration - my real world query does not have `from (select 1)` but selects from a view*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the SQLite [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#views) (my emphasis):

> Subqueries might also need to be materialized when they appear in the
>   `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` statement. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM ex1 JOIN (SELECT b FROM ex2) AS t ON t.b=ex1.a;
> ```
>
> Depending on the query, SQLite might need to materialize the `(SELECT
>   b FROM ex2)` subquery into a temporary table, then perform the join
>   between ex1 and the temporary table. The query optimizer tries to
>   avoid this by "flattening" the query. In the previous example the
>   query can be flattened, and SQLite will automatically transform the
>   query into
>
> ```
> SELECT ex1.*, ex2.b FROM ex1 JOIN ex2 ON ex2.b=ex1.a;
> ```
>
> More complex
>   queries may or may not be able to employ query flattening to avoid the
>   temporary table. **Whether or not the query can be flattened depends on
>   such factors as whether or not the subquery or outer query contain
>   aggregate functions, `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` clauses, `LIMIT` clauses, and
>   so forth.** The rules for when a query and cannot be flattened are very
>   complex and are beyond the scope of this document.

You may be able to work around the problem [with a view](http://www.mentby.com/simon-smith/re-random-does-not-keep-value-in-subquery.html), but it seems that in this case at least, adding a dummy `union` is enough to prevent "flattening":

```
select op, op
from (select abs(random())%10 as op from (select 1) union all select 1 where 1=2);

6|6
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that the result will not change in the future version of sqlite, It will be better not to relay on actual implementation. Try this:

```
SELECT op, op FROM (select abs(x.r)%10 as op from ((select 1) JOIN (select random() r)) x);
op          op        
----------  ----------
8           8
```